# What is the meaning of this condition for who the act applies to?

Tags: canada, rental-property, british-columbia

In the [BC residential tenancy act](http://www.bclaws.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/02078_01#section2), it states

> This Act does not apply to... living accommodation in which the tenant
>   shares bathroom or kitchen facilities with the owner of that
>   accommodation

So if the owner of the house rents it out, but also lives in it, the tenants are no longer protected by the act? Does I understand this correctly? This seems a bit unfair, I've seen houses before where the landlord lives in a shared house and uses the same kitchen as the other tenants do.

Also does

> Living accommodation owned or operated by an educational institution
>   and provided by that institution to its students or employees

Mean that students living on a university campus aren't protected by the act?

Comment: The choice of the word "provided" is interesting. If it means rented by or leased to why not say that? I think it might be referring to a specific situation where housing is included in a price or compensation package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you rent a room in the owner's house the act does not apply; there may be another one that does.

Similarly for student accommodation.